# How to prevent race condition or reduce its possibility

Tags: c#, caching, redis, race-condition, system-design

I'm trying to reduce the possibility of a race condition if invalidation of my redis cache occurs at the same time I'm retrieving from the cache. Note that invalidation and retrieval happen on two different systems, so I don't know whether this is happening at the same time.

System 1:

```
InValidateCache() {
  _cache.remove(key);
}
```

System 2:

```
GetCacheKey() {
   string key = _cache.get();
}
```

Here, key could return the dirty string which has been invalidated in System 1 (since invalidation of cache in System 1 could happen after retrieval of cache in System 2).
How do I make sure that doesn't happen? Is there a retry or another approach I could take to reduce the possibility?

Comment: What is the behavior you expect here? The cache will return the value if it has the value. it does not know if it is dirty or not. If the get operation happens before the remove operation, it will return whatever data it has. it does not know that the next operation will be to remove the key.

Comment: Thanks Chetan, wondering if I can retry the "Get" x number of times to avoid the race condition? something like try to execute the Get 5 times and if the Get returns nothing once, break the loop?

Answer (score 0):

The question lacks the context or usecase for which you need such a solution. However based on the details provided I will try to answer the question.

You could use Mutex based approach to access the cache store and get distributed locks which will prevent the race condition. An overview of the reading/writing operation will look like

**Steps:**

> - Acquire the lock
> - Perform the operation (read | write)
> - Release the lock

This will be similar to using a Database lock if not exactly the same. You can use the same cache store to acquire the lock. Take a reference from this [Ruby gem](https://github.com/kenn/redis-mutex).

However, I feel it will be an unnecessary layer between the cache store and application unless you want to attach some business logic to the operation. For eg: Two different systems trying to update the cache key at the same time which takes into consideration the previous value of the cache read operation.